# SoundPool Not Loading in Android App

Tags: android, audio, loading, playback

I'm making an app where I'm trying to load a single sound onto a SoundPool so I can manage the playback rate when I want, play it when I want, and release it when I want.  However, my SoundPool is not loading.  I've tried to change a lot of different things and nothing seems to work. I put a Log.d in the OnLoadComplete function to see if it loads, and the log doesn't appear when running...  Maybe after looking at my code somebody else could help me.  Thanks!

```
private int currentVoice = 0;
private SoundPool voices = null;
....
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
....
    voices = new SoundPool(1, 3, 0);
    voices.setOnLoadCompleteListener(this);
....
}
private void giveSentence() throws IOException {
....
voices.release();
currentVoice = voices.load(this, sentences[index].voice, 1);
voices.play(currentVoice, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);

public void onLoadComplete(SoundPool soundPool, int sampleId, int status) {
    soundPool.play(sampleId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1f);
    boolean loaded = true;
    Log.d("Game","Is it loaded? " + loaded);
}
```

Comment: Fixed myself, I was doing voices.release(); before anything was loaded.  For some reason that just turned the SoundPool off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed myself, I was doing voices.release(); before anything was loaded. For some reason that just turned the SoundPool off.  Took out that line and did voices.release() after I checked if it was already loaded.  Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your sound pool somewhere in a [onCreate](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&q=android%20onCreate&fp=1&cad=b) method, I guess.

```
 private SoundPool voices;

 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    voices = new SoundPool(1, 3, 0);
    voices.setOnLoadCompleteListener(this);
 }
```

Comment: Sorry I left out a piece of code.  Those are already in the onCreate method.  So that's not the problem...